# textContent/innerHTML doesn't change text

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

The textContent of two elements are not being changed, although the function is called, and both values are present. The script is located in the bottom of the index.html and i have also tried innerHTML and innerText. The element that is being changed is here:

```
if(projectComplete){
  totalCompletedProjects++;
  var projectHtml = "<div class='projectCard bg-success' id="+ doc.id +"> <h2 class='projectCardTitle' style='text-decoration: line-through'> " + doc.data().projectName + " </h2> <div id='projectCardTimeDiv'>Estimated time <h2 class='projectCardTime'>  " + doc.data().projectEstimatedTime + "</h2>       Used time </div></div>"
}else {
  var projectHtml = "<div class='projectCard' id="+ doc.id +"> <h2 class='projectCardTitle'> " + doc.data().projectName + " </h2> <div id='projectCardTimeDiv'>Estimated time <span id='projectCardTime'>"+ doc.data().projectEstimatedTime+ "</span></div></div>"
}
insertAndAddHtml("#projectContent", projectHtml);
insertAndAddHtml("#projectContentModal", projectHtml);
```

And the function to render the update is here:

```
var renderUpdateProject = function(change){
  console.log(projectInFocus);
  console.log("renderUpdateProject called " + change.doc.data().projectName + "   " + change.doc.id);
var projectNameElement = document.getElementById(change.doc.id).getElementsByClassName("projectCardTitle")[0];
var projectTimeElement = document.getElementById(change.doc.id).getElementsByClassName("projectCardTime")[0];
 console.log("renderUpdateProject called " + projectNameElement + "   :  " + projectTimeElement);
projectNameElement.textContent = change.doc.data().projectName;
projectTimeElement.textContent  = change.doc.data().projectEstimatedTime;
}
```

This is where the function gets called

```
var grabProjectsFromDB = function(){
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  db.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("projects").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {

          if (change.type === "added") {
             if (!projects.has(change.doc.id))  {
          renderProject(change.doc);
          projects.set(change.doc.id, [change.doc.data().projectName, change.doc.data().completed, change.doc.data().dateCompleted]);

          }
        }      
          if (change.type === "modified") {
            console.log("modififed item " + change.doc.data().projectName);
            renderUpdateProject(change);
          }
          if (change.type === "removed") {


          }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: What does `change` look like? How is `change.doc.data()` calculated? How and where is it updated?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Change is from firestore, but it can't be where the problem lies, as the correct change.doc.id and change.doc values are being logged in the console.log.  I will edit the post and show the code for the change doc.